# Retrieving SMTP conversation in SwiftMailer

Tags: php, swiftmailer

I am using [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) to send emails and my site is all of a sudden having timeout issues when trying to send an email.

I need to extract the "SMTP conversation" so my host can debug it.

Is there any code that can give me this?

```
include('SwiftMailer/swift_required.php');
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.example.com', 587);
$transport->setUsername('username');
$transport->setPassword('password');
$swift = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

// Create a message
$message = new Swift_Message($subject);
$message->setFrom($from);
$message->setBody($message, $content_type, SITE_CHARSET);
$message->setTo($to);

try {
    $swift->send($message);
} catch (Swift_TransportException $e) {
    // Log array for further inspection
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to take a look at the [SwiftMailer Logger Plugin](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/plugins.html) which will allow you log all the interactions between your client and the SMTP server.

There is two types of loggers available:

- The `ArrayLogger` - (Keeps a collection of log messages inside an array. The array content can be cleared or dumped out to the screen)
- The `EchoLogger` (Prints output to the screen in realtime. Handy for very rudimentary debug output)

You can register the plugin using either:

```
$logger = new Swift_Plugins_Loggers_ArrayLogger();
$swift->registerPlugin(new Swift_Plugins_LoggerPlugin($logger));
```

or

```
$logger = new Swift_Plugins_Loggers_EchoLogger();
$swift->registerPlugin(new Swift_Plugins_LoggerPlugin($logger));
```

Just make sure you have the plugin installed and that your class autoloader can access the required class on demand.

Refer to the documentation for further details.

Comment: That's great but the logger doesn't seem to give me the SMTP Conversation... Comparing what it gives me to [this example](http://www.earthinfo.org/example-smtp-conversation/), it's very different. The logger gives me: `The error: ++ Starting Swift_SmtpTransport !! Connection could not be established with host smtp.example.com [Connection timed out #110]`

Comment: Oh. Well in that case you can safely assume that either your SMTP hostname or the port are invalid (or inaccessible). When the connection fails, you won't see much of an SMTP conversation anyway. Try figuring out why it doesn't work. Check if something with the SMTP server has changed. Also see if you can connect manually through `telnet` (and if it doesn't work, find out whether its a firewall issue you are dealing with).

Comment: Thanks @SquareCat. Turned out to be some sort of connection congestion which eventually sorted itself out after about 24 hours. The logger was helpful though and appreciate your help sharing it :)

Answer (score 2):

Example with Laravel 
Dump the conversation to log:

```
$content = 'Test';
$title = 'Test now()= ' . date("Y-m-d",time());                
$logger = new \Swift_Plugins_Loggers_ArrayLogger();
Mail::getSwiftMailer()->registerPlugin(new \Swift_Plugins_LoggerPlugin($logger));
Mail::send('emails.send', ['title' => $title, 'content' => $content], function ($message){
 $message->from('fromuser@mydomain.com');
 $message->to('touser@mydomain.com');
});
Log::info($logger->dump());
```

And send.blade.php at \resources\emails

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body style="background: orange; color: white">
<h1>{{$title}}</h1>
<p>{{$content}}</p>

AGARCIA - 2018
</body>
</html>
```